# Как центрировать flex-контейнер

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Хотелось как в гриде. Чтобы сам флех-контейнер было по центру или например если justify-content:space-between был равномерный отступ между блоками, но на следующем ряде все начались вначале как flex-start. Ну те-кто работали с гридом думаю меня понимает. Донес как смог.

Вот код -->

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
}

.list__item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

а хотелось бы сделать вот так но на flex-e

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list__item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понимаю прикола, людям дали удобный инструмент `grid`, а они вечно пытаются сделать через одно место не подходящим инструментом.

Answer (score 0):

> а хотелось бы сделать вот так но на flex-e

Предложу такой вариант...

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 30px;
}
.list::after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}

.list__item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: НЕ, следующий ряд должен начаться сначала. Тут две элементы ушли в две стороны

Comment: @Dias, добавил в стилях...

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это как раз тот случай, когда `grid` справляется лучше, чем `flex`. Даже не уверен, что это можно реализовать на флексах без костылей, т.к у `flex` нет такого понятия, как отдельная "строка".

Единственное, что смог придумать -

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list__item {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
    <div class="list__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```